# Data from a joined table where the join table doesn't have an entry

Tags: sql

I have a table of answers, and a table of questions, and a join table to join them. The quesions table has questions, and the answers table has answers to those questions. The problem being, this is a multi choice setup. So the answers will have some right answers and some wrong answers for a question.

Whether an answer is right or not is indicated by a boolean - is_right.

How can I find which quesions have answers where there *isn't* a right answer (and similarly, where there isn't a wrong answer) in the answers table?

Comment: how do you say that there is no wrong answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM questions
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT TRUE
  FROM answers a1
  WHERE a1.question_id = questions.question_id
  AND a1.is_right
)
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT TRUE
  FROM answers a2
  WHERE a2.question_id = questions.question_id
  AND !a2.is_right
)
```

If you want to avoid the subselect for some reason:

```
SELECT question_id,
       SUM(is_right) AS right_answers,
       SUM(!is_right) AS wrong_answers
FROM questions
JOIN answers ON answers.question_id = questions.question_id
GROUP BY question_id
HAVING right_answers > 0
AND wrong_answers = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have a join table, since an answer would only have one question.

Without a join table, to query for questions where there are no right answers:

```
SELECT questions.*
FROM questions LEFT OUTER JOIN answers
  ON questions.id = answer.question_id AND answer.is_right = false
WHERE answer.id IS NULL
```

With a join table named answers_questions, the SQL would be:

```
SELECT questions.*
FROM questions
  LEFT OUTER JOIN answers_questions
    ON answers_questions.question_id = question.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN answers
    ON answers_questions.answer_id = answer.id AND answer.is_right = false
WHERE answer.id IS NULL
```

This will also give you the questions for which there are no answers linked.
To get the questions for which there are no right answers, among the questions which are linked to an answer, change the first LEFT OUTER JOIN to an INNER JOIN.